# unwanted box around HTML body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style my page with CSS, and I've set the background color. Except my page keeps displaying a white box around all the content in the body of my page. Literally, all I have to do is set the background color, and I automatically get a white box around all the content in the body of my HTML page. I know it has something to do with bootstrap because when I get rid of the bootstrap link needed to use bootstrap in my index page, the white box goes away, but so do my nav-pills and bootstrap buttons. So, how do I get rid of it?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap    
/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
html {
     background-color: #FFFFCC;  
}
```

Comment: may i know your page url?

Comment: Look for a normalize/reset stylesheet. The browser adds some styling by default that you don't always want.

Comment: @TarunMahashwari That's not required, this is done by default

Comment: Debug, use Developer Tools, in Chrome or Firefox and inspect element.

Comment: VeeeneX, your comment helped a little bit. I was able to do what you asked and found out that it has something to do with Bootstrap, though if I remove the required <link> to use it, it not only gets rid of the white box, but it also gets right of my nav-pills and bootstrap buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Reset the `margin` and `padding` of body

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Browser set the `margin` and `padding` by default. You can override that using above rule. Add this at the start of your CSS.

Comment: That didn't help, sorry.

Comment: @lady8506 Can you add complete code here, or create a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

It's because by default browsers set certain styles on elements by default. I believe html, body has `padding: 10px` or `margin: 10px` by default.

A good base to start with to give yourself a clean start is to use something like normalize (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. First, the link for bootstrap needed to come before my link for CSS in my index.html, so that CSS would override bootstrap's default styling. Second, I needed to specify background color in the body tag, instead of in the html tag of my style.css file. Problem solved!!